# How to change the app icon in Action Bar in SDK 22?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Now I make app with SDK 22,but the Action Bar's app icon dispear.
Here are my code.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/overflowButton</item>
    </style>
    <!--ActionBar-->
    <style name="ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/bg</item>
        <item name="background">@color/bg</item>
        <item name="android:title">@string/test</item>
        <item name="title">@string/test</item>
        <item name="icon">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>   <!-- here I want to show the app icon,but it can't-->
        <item name="android:icon">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>
    </style>
    <style name="overflowButton">
        <item name="android:src">@mipmap/ic_add_black_48dp</item>
        <item name="android:showAsAction"></item>
    </style>
    <style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>
</resources>
```

I have try to solve it by android deceloper,but fail.I also try many other ways,it also fail.Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, your main issue is that application icon do not appear on `actionbar`.

For that you need to set display option to `actionbar`.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

PS you need to import `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` to your activity.